# android/java how do you get audio file from a server response?

Tags: java, android, audio

I am making an app where i have to download an audio file from a server and save it to the android phone. I was able to get the binary string using response handler and using the string for stream. The audio file is downloaded but the file size is larger and it has additional(special characters) characters when you open the audio file in notepad.

Code to download file from server

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://12.2.4.212:8080/v1/AUTH_fa32121dfaccsa12dascadsa2/audio/"+filename);
httpget.setHeader("X-Auth-Token","MIIKKgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIKGzCCChcCAQExCTAHBgUrcNA=");
httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

ResponseHandler<String> rh = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
```

code to save the file to android

```
InputStream is;
FileOutputStream fos;
File directory = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), "App/Audio");
File musicFile = new File(directory, filename);
if(!musicFile.exists()){
    try {
        cacheDirectory.mkdirs();
        musicFile.createNewFile();
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        fos = new FileOutputStream(musicFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        fos.write(buffer);
        is.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, I have already try other stackoverflow suggestions but not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use **DownloadManager**

```
String dir = Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC;
            dir += "/klp";
            File fileDir = new File(dir);
            if (!fileDir.isDirectory()) {
                fileDir.mkdir();
            }

            Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Download song " + name,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Download File
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));
            request.setDescription(nameFile);
            request.setTitle(name);
            // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to
            // compile your app
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            }
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(dir, nameFile);

            // get download service and enqueue file
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Could you show me your logcat? Because my code works fine. I am using in my app (which published)